# how to use numpy.random to generate a matrix of int number

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

as I have mentioned in title, I fail to make it happened in my code. Here is my code, I try to use the two methods, but eventually it still cannot work.

```
# using python 2.7.12
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20141001', periods = 7)
import numpy as np
dates1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7,3), index =dates, columns = list('ABC'))
print dates1
dates2 =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100), index =dates, columns = list('ABC'))
```

Comment: You should tell us specifically what line doesn't work, what result you get, and what result you want to get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a matrix of random integers, you would write

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(low=0,high=100,size=(7,3) )
print x
```

`low` is the minimum integer that can be drawn, and `high` is the maximum integer plus one that can be drawn (i.e. `high=100` means the maximum integer that can be drawn is 99). `size` determines the shape of the numpy array that will be returned. The output of the above code (given the random seed used on my machine) is:

```
array([[15, 97,  2],
       [88,  3,  6],
       [64, 97, 13],
       [18, 44, 75],
       [ 4, 59, 10],
       [97, 83, 73],
       [97, 21, 28]])
```

You can then cast this into a pandas `DataFrame` as you were before:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

dates2 =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0,high=100,size=(7,3)),\
          index =dates, columns = list('ABC'))
```